# Pandas reorder categories working with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, categories

Is there a way of using `df['Column'].astype('category')` and `df['Column'].cat.reorder_categories()` to list NaN in one of the positions? `.astype()` doesn't appear to affect NaN values in my dataframe.

Basically for df['Column'].unique() I have:

['Moderate' 'Liberal' 'Somewhat Conservative' 'Somewhat liberal' 'Very Liberal' 'Very Conservative' 'Conservative' nan]

And I would like to get it to:

['Very Liberal' < 'Liberal' < 'Somewhat liberal' < 'Moderate' < 'Somewhat Conservative' < 'Conservative' < 'Very Conservative' < nan]

I have tried:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].astype('category')

df['Column'] = df['Column'].cat.reorder_categories(['Very Liberal', 'Liberal', 'Somewhat liberal', 'Moderate', 'Somewhat Conservative', 'Conservative', 'Very Conservative', np.nan], ordered=True)
```

But it throws the error "ValueError: items in new_categories are not the same as in old categories" indicating that np.nan doesn't exist in the categories.

So I guess I'm wondering how to specify/represent NaN as a category, and how to order it within categories of a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from missing non-NA categories in your column. You need to add them with [`add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html)

You should however **not** add NaN as category, NaN is always a possible category with code `-1`. Thus NaN is not directly orderable within the categories. You can however chose the NaN ordering position in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and the `na_position='last'` parameter.

```
order = ['Very Liberal', 'Liberal', 'Somewhat liberal', 'Moderate', 'Somewhat Conservative', 'Conservative', 'Very Conservative']

df['Column'] = (df['Column']
                .cat.add_categories(set(order).difference(df['Column'].cat.categories))
                .cat.reorder_categories(order, ordered=True)
               )
```

Now let's sort:

```
df['Column'].sort_values(na_position='last')
```

If you really want an orderable NaN, use a placeholder string such as `'NAN'` and set it as category.

Comment: Thanks very much! As I started to ask this question I wondered "Should I even be doing this?" The context is a class I'm working on with others and this portion deals with visualizations. It has been a little hard to figure out what to do with NaN values and this certainly helps.